# How To Get EIP-198 in Solidity Working With Ganache-cli

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm trying to use EIP 198 (https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-198.md) locally on ganache-cli, has anyone done that?

I keep getting an unknown opcode error.... I've ran ganache-cli with the ganache-cli -k byzantium argument already :\

The contract I'm specifically trying to deploy is: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x0feedd6091b9448b376ebb7f4d756b6f823439db#contracts

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all I has to do was run it with `ganache-cli -k=petersburg` as I was running solidity>=0.5.0